# Facebook Open Graph Object Properties is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my url: http://rosarioferta.com/rosarioo/articulo.jsp?id=10314

the open graph is not working... the debuuger:

show me:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frosarioferta.com%2Frosarioo%2Farticulo.jsp%3Fid%3D10314

Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

But the tags are in the page:

```
<!--Facebook-->

<meta property="fb:admins" content="1192060266" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="210626255676435" /> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://rosarioferta.com/rosarioo/articulo.jsp?id=10314"/>    
<meta property="og:title" content="Nuevo Clasificado!-Ipad 1 32G iOS 4.3.5 Original Completo" />
<meta property="og:description"  content="Nuevo Clasificado!-Ipad 1 32G iOS 4.3.5 Original Completo" /> 
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES" />  
<meta property="og:image" content="http://rosarioferta.com/tmp/2992699077868379919412068529213362854757922.jpg" />

<!--Facebook-->
```

the share button is not working correctly. not taking the title,the descriptiond and the thumbail image.

Answer (score 0):

http://rosarioferta.com/rosarioo/articulo.jsp?id=10314

HTTP Status 404 - /rosarioo/articulo.jsp

type Status report

message /rosarioo/articulo.jsp

description The requested resource (/rosarioo/articulo.jsp) is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a cookie or a session to render a different page ?

If you clear your cache and disable Javascript, you'll see the same thing as the Facebook Scraper: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rosarioferta.com%2Frosarioo%2Farticulo.jsp%3Fid%3D10314

Comment: it seems you're rendering the page a different way if the Cookie JSESSIONID is set...

Comment: I'am using a cookie and session with java code not with javascript I deleted all javascript code here: http://rosarioferta.com:8080/javier/articulo2.jsp?id=10314  but not working.. The problems is something else.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. Delete all the cookies and see for yourself

Comment: You're using a cookie to render the page a different way, that's why it's not working on Facebook

Comment: i deleted all the code and now it's working.. http://rosarioferta.com:8080/javier/articulo3.jsp?id=10314 I'll have to put the code in parts for detecting problem